# Restrict samba-user for upload files based on file size

Tags: samba, quota

Is there any possibilities to restrict Samba user's to a maximum file size?

Ex, If a samba-user uploads a file onto the server that's more than 100 MB (like video or compressed files), Samba, or the system receiving the file, should not allow it.

Answer (score 2):

So there is a solution.

Considering Samba share size = 10GB

If you want an user not to use more than 1GB then you can use **user quota** management as described [here](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=quota)

Now as of your question, you need to restrict copy and paste of your samba users, then follow the steps here,

```
# vi /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Edit this configuration file and append like this to all user whom you need to restrict

```
savvy       hard  fsize  102400
```

So the samba user `savvy` cannot file transfer beyond 100MB. 
For the changes to take effect logout and log back in or restart your system.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, How about guest user ? I've enabled guest user on one of the share on Samba configuration.

Comment: `savvy       hard  fsize  102400`
Change this line to 
`guest       hard  fsize  102400`

It would be great if you accept my answer and upvote as appreciating in this page. Thanks

Comment: I've enabled these two things on my smb.conf, "public = yes, guest ok = yes". It'll create file with "nobody  nogroup". So now how can I restrict with /etc/security/limits.conf ???

Comment: Same rule applies there, `#cat /etc/passwd` There you will see a user nobody, `nobody hard fsize 102400` Will do the trick. ;)

Comment: File restrict is not working with user nobady. how can I check whether limit applied or not, without copy a file ?

Comment: Consider filebig.zip is 150 MB login to share and now paste filebig.zip  into it. It will throw an error.

Comment: Actually I tried with more than 5 files, Even 1 GB sized also not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12049/discussion-between-ruban-savvy-and-kumar)

Comment: doesn't work (anymore?) - see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post, but just in case someone stumbles on it it's good to know that Ruban Savvy's recipe doesn't work (anymore ?), so don't spend too much time on it. At least it's not working on Samba 4. I got a straight answer from the Samba team (the full discussion can be found on the Samba's February mailing list, https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2021-February.txt.gz, grep for "limits.conf" to get to the relevant mails)

If someone has an idea it would be great, but according to my research it's basically not possible to limit the size of individual files on a Samba share (nor is it possible on a Windows Server).